# How to create a loop using STL list in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl

This is an interview question: How to create a loop using the STL list container?

I am a newbie. I searched this question and did not find any. If this is an old question please give me the link and delete this post.

Thank you all!

Comment: That's a poorly worded question.  You should have asked for clarification.  Did they want to know how to iterate over `std::list`?

Comment: This is not my interview question. But I am sure it is not a question about traversing through the list. The complete question actually asks you to make a loop and then detect it.

Comment: maybe put the code you want in a destructor and create a list of N of these objects?

Comment: Is this question about detecting loops in linked lists? http://ostermiller.org/find_loop_singly_linked_list.html

Comment: @BoBTFish That's part of the original question. I think I am more concerned with the first part of the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> *How to create a loop using the STL list container?*

You can't.

`std::list` has a beginning and an end. All access to the data structure is carefully controlled so that a standard-compliant program simply cannot produce a non-terminating list.

**P.s.**  I'm assuming that the interviewer actually meant to say "`std::list`" instead of "STL list."

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer is: It can happen when more than one thread is manipulating the `list` structure at the same time. Suppose two threads want to `push_back` into an already formed `list`. If the list already has `b` and `a`, the circular list could look like:

```
  .--------------------------.
 (                            )
  `-> a <-> SENTINEL <-> b <-'
```

And one thread inserts `c` at the same time another inserts `d`. They each want to attach to the back of the `SENTINEL` like this:

```
a <-> c <-> SENTINEL
a <-> d <-> SENTINEL
```

However, the could end up making a loop:

```
   .------------.
a. `-.           )
  `-> c <-> d <-'
             <--> SENTINEL <-> b (<-> a)
```

The forward links are fine: `b -> a -> c -> d`
But the reverse links will loop: `d -> c -> d` ...

This can happen because the pointers of the SENTINEL is being read, dereferenced, and modified without mutual exclusion.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I think I do not understand your diagram.

Comment: @KevinHu: I changed the example, and provided a more detailed explanation.